# Headers and footers for listing environment?

Tags: spacing, listings, page-breaking

What I need to be able to do is apply a header and footer when I use the listings environment.  I have a few requirements:

- The header and footer should be outside the listing itself, i.e. they are not part of the listing content.
- The amount of space between the header and the listing should be the same as the amount of space between the footer and the listing.
- The amount of space between the listing and the header/footer should not be rubber, i.e. TeX should not be able adjust the header/footer closer to or farther from the listing.
- The header and footer may not be the same for every listing.
- Page breaks should not be possible between the header/footer and the listing.
- Page breaks should be possible within the listing itself.

As far as I can tell I can get most of the way there if use `minipage`:

```
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\codeHeaderFooter}{}

\lstnewenvironment{code}[2][]{
  \lstset{language=c++,aboveskip=12pt,belowskip=12pt,#1}
  \renewcommand{\codeHeaderFooter}{#2}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}
  \codeHeaderFooter{}
} {
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{flushright}
    \codeHeaderFooter{}
  \end{flushright}
}

\begin{code}{header/footer}
std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
\end{code}
```

The problem is that minipage doesn't allow page breaks, so the listing cannot span multiple pages.  Other solutions I've tried (i.e. a combination of `\nopagebreak[4]` and `\vspace`, and `\raggedbottom`) fail to either (a) prevent page breaks between the header/footer and the listing, or (b) prevent TeX from adjusting the space between the header/footer and the listing.  Floats are not an option.

Any ideas about how I can satisfy all of the requirement above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only package I knew doing things you want is package `longtable`.  It has special headers and footers for tables spanning over more than one page.

The package `listings` has no headers and footers defined you want, so one way to solve your problem would be to study the code for headers and footers in longtable and change package `listings` and include there the code for similar header and footers.

Both packages are tricky one so I guess only the maintainer of the packages can help you.  Perhaps you ask the maintainer of `listings` to add such a functionality?