# Is there a list environment with (double sided) page headers?

Tags: header-footer, lists, double-sided

This question is an extension of [Headers and footers for listing environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62990/5763): I have a list of objects (like tables or simply boxes) that should be vertically stacked (so it's a list) and is longer than one page and I want to put a header (and maybe a footer) for the list on every page (but I don't want to use the page header/footer for the list header/footer). And I need a double sided solution (different headers on even/odd pages).

Currently I use `longtable` for that, but that doesn't work well in a double sided layout (see [How to make a doublesided longtable with a doublesided header?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116331/5763)).

Comment: Just stumbled upon this question doing janitorial work. To be honest, i don't understand what you are after exactly. If you are still interested, an MWE (as often) may help. If you are not interested anymore, can we close this?

Comment: @Johannes_B: I don't _need_ this anymore, but I'm still interested. I'll try to expand the question, although I believe it's clear already.